# is there a more efficient way to code this with ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three tables:

1. Users
2. Questions
3. User_Questions

   1.user questions has the columns user_id, question_id, and answer

I want to find a random question that has not been answered and **thus does not have a row in the user_questions table**.

If every question has been answered, then return any random question.

I'm told this can be done with an OUTER JOIN, but I'm a SQL noob and I'm not sure how to do that in Rails.
This is what I have:

```
def next_question          
  q = Question.all - Question.joins(:user_questions).where
       (user_questions: { user_id: user_id })
  q = Question.all if q.empty?
  return q[rand(q.size)]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's hardly ever a good reason for calling the `all` method on a model class. This loads every single record in the database of that type into memory, and unless you're absolutely certain this is a small set of records, you could potentially hang your entire system. Even then it's extremely bad form to load in *everything* and then cherry pick one thing and discard the rest. It's like ordering one of every single item from Amazon, picking out the pen you want, and throwing the rest of the delivery in the trash.

What you probably want is something where you randomly select *one* record that has not been assigned yet. That probably looks something like this:

```
Question.where('id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM user_questions WHERE user_id=?)', user_id).order('RAND()').first
```

The problem with a `JOIN` is that you're going to find records that have matches in the `user_questions` table and not the inverse.

This query presumes that the number of questions answered by a user is relatively small or that `NOT IN` could get dramatically more expensive.

Comment: different versions of SQL seem to want different versions of 'RANDOM()' but yeah, this does it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN for this. A normal INNER JOIN will only include rows that match the join condition, a LEFT JOIN will include matching rows and will flesh out the unmatched rows by putting NULLs in all the columns (the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) have a reasonable description).

So, you do a LEFT JOIN and then look for an unmatched row by looking for a NULL. The SQL would look sort of like this:

```
select ...
from questions
left outer join user_questions on questions.id = user_questions.question_id
where user_questions.question_id is null
```

That would give you all the questions that haven't been answered. In ActiveRecord, you could do something like this:

```
Question.joins('left outer join user_questions on question.id = user_questions.question_id')
        .where(:user_questions => { :question_id => nil })
        .limit(1)
```

You might want to play with random ordering as well but that should get you started. If that doesn't give you a match then you can grab a random question with something like this:

```
n = Questions.count
q = Questions.offset(rand(n)).limit(1)
```

You could do the above with `Questions.order('random()').limit(1)` as well but `ORDER BY random()` can be unpleasant with a large database; getting the count should be pretty fast so doing the random picking in Ruby should be quick enough and it won't make your database hate you.

Also have a look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for ways to tidy up that `joins`, I'm working with a database with a slightly non-standard structure so I have to do things the long way sometimes; ActiveRecord is refusing to do a LEFT JOIN for me unless I spell it out, YMMV.